# Keep background of my Memo white with dark theme

Tags: ios, firemonkey

When dark mode on mobile (ios) is enabled the background of my `TMemo` become black.

How I can keep it white ?
It's look like I havn't hand on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color of a `TMemo` in the style data.

Double click the `StyleManager` and scroll down in the `Structure` view to `memostyle`. Open it and select `background`.

Then, in the `Object Inspector` select the `Fill` property and click it open. You can now change the `Color` property to white (#FFFFFFFF).

Close and answer `Yes` to question about applying changes.